# Why my answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Could I know the reason of deleting my answer for this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/433748/use-terminal-to-translate-some-text?

I know that there exist a similar question but that appears after I answered.. Moreover why you can't just merger the questions?! Why did you delete +4 upvoted answer?!

Answer (score 10):

From my part (since it was I who did this), you had answered the question already on the duplicate.

Since you effectively had recognised that the question was a duplicate and had correctly answered on the correct question, my role was simple - to play the janitor and thus cleanup by removing the answer.

There was no reason to merge here since you had already answered the question.

---

Most traffic to Stack Exchange sites is via search engines.  To redirect users to the correct question, Stack Exchange uses the policy of redirection as explained here:

- [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr)

Now ordinarily I would normally leave questions and answers alone unless they start to receive high traffic (visits).  In this case, you had answered the question on the duplicate - thus leaving two answers on separate questions would have been nonsensical - you potentially would be benefiting twice with the same answer.

Hence the janitorial rule here applies - cleanup and move on to find similar stuff to tidy up.

Comment: I totally understand that but why I loose reputation?! couldn't you just make it duplicate without delete? As I see there are much duplicate answers and not deleted!! I just want to understand the criteria of choosing duplicates to be deleted.

Comment: there you go - hope that explains stuff.

Comment: I understand that and thanks for your time. Sometimes there are unfairness